# Collect iOS application logs automatically through script

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript, automator, xcuitest

I have been going crazy over this, is there a way to collect iOS application logs through script? I am working on an iOS application and have written some UI Tests now in order to gather logs i had to manually take it, is there a way some utility may be in form of script which i can fire and download the logs on my mac. Ofcourse my devices under test are connected to my mac machine. I have been going over cfgutil, apple script but so far no luck. Anybody with knowledge and care to help. Please do so!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

no. you can't, mainly because the output of debug in xcode is handled by xcode it self

Comment: That's it... no other way... there's got to be some way.. isn't it??